# Trying to find this specific manufacturer for a diode

Tags: power, diodes, power-electronics, snubber

I am trying to find these specific diodes and who made it. Thanks for your time in advance. They could be tvs diodes also
[image]

Comment: There's a clearly visible logo with a C and rotated S. Looking up diode manufacturer logos may help. Indeed https://line.17qq.com/articles/bgdfhebz.html shows it's actually GS - General Semiconductors https://www.google.com/search?q=General+Semiconductors&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjb-Mehxu7vAhUHQRoKHYi_DkwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=General+Semiconductors&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQGDoECAAQHjoCCAA6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgYIABAFEB5Q-NACWJGWCmDNmApoAXAAeACAAaoBiAGgFZIBBTExLjE1mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=neluYJu2KIeCaYj_uuAE&bih=882&biw=1920#imgrc=Uuq4Hpug6NGYhM

Comment: Thanks Mate!! I did not know there was a sheet specifically for the manafacturers.